# Redux reducer returning array of data into initial array (nested arrays)

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-redux

I have a React/Redux project handling blog posts. The initial state loaded up is

```
const initialState = {
    visibilityFilter: 'SHOW_ALL',
    currentPostId: -1,
    posts: [],
    topics: []
}
```

this action calls a NodeJs api to pull the initial posts:

```
function receivePosts(json) {
    return {
        type: C.RECEIVE_POSTS,
        payload: json
    }
}

const fetchPosts = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: C.REQUEST_POSTS})

    return fetch('http://localhost:3333/api/posts')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(json)))
    .then(res => dispatch({type: C.CANCEL_REQUEST}))
}
```

from a posts.json file:

```
[{
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Post 1",
    "author": "author 1",
    "anonymous": false,
    "statusId": 0,
    "topicId": 2,
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "<p>This is a very long post</p><p>This is a very long post</p><p>This is a very long post</p><p>This is a very long post</p><p>This is a very long post</p><p>This is a very long post</p><p>This is a very long post</p><p>This is a very long post</p>",
    "createdAt": "2018-03-28",
    "updatedAt": "2018-03-29",
    "videoUrl": "",
    "imageUrl": ""
},
{...post 2},
{...post 3}
]
```

which then dispatches this reducer

```
export const posts = (state=[], action) => { 
    ...
    switch(action.type) {
        case C.RECEIVE_POSTS:
        return [
            ...state,
            action.payload
        ]
}
```

But the final state looks like this:

```
{
    "visibilityFilter":"SHOW_ALL",
    "posts":[[
        {"id":0,"title":"Post 1","author":"author1","anonymous":false,"statusId":0,"topicId":2,"contentType":"html","content":"<p>This is a very long post</p><p>This is a very long post</p><p>This is a very long post</p><p>This is a very long post</p><p>This is a very long post</p><p>This is a very long post</p><p>This is a very long post</p><p>This is a very long post</p>","createdAt":"2018-03-28","updatedAt":"2018-03-29","videoUrl":"","imageUrl":""},
        {...post 2},
        {...post 3}
   ]],
    "topics":[],
    "currentPostId":-1
}
```

Notice how "posts" is a nested array? `[[]]` How is that happening? I also tried `json.map(post => post)` in receivePosts. And tried an `Object.assign({}, state, action.payload)` in the reducer. What am i missing about how to completely replace the initial empty array with the new array of data?

Comment: I usually return an object in the reducer, not an array `return { ...state, action.payload }`

Comment: You could spread your your data like so: `return [
            ...state,
            ...action.payload
        ]`

Comment: @AmrAly: `return [ ...state, ...action.payload ]` worked!

Comment: @D.Messier Glad that your problem has been solved